Systemd stopped/froze on boot while loading modules on Ubuntu 20.04.6 x86_64, systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.20
Good day, I have Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (kernel 5.15.0-113-generic) dual booted with Windows 11 installation on my device, but it always stuck/hang/freeze while systemd is loading modules at boot on these known conditions:

Power-on after shutting down in to Gnome or Windows
Power-on after shutting down via power-off/shutdown option in GDM3 or Windows log-in screen

Temporary fixes:

Restarting via displayed option or terminal command after/before logging in to either OS
Power-off by holding the power button then power-on while in GDM3 or Windows log-in screen

Troubleshooting trials:

I tried waiting for something to happen when the issue is occuring, but nothing came up,
I tried disabling chromeos_pstore module from loading (since systemd seem to stop around the time where the module is loaded), didn't do anything,
I tried disabling secure boot, didn't work as well.

Additional info:
I tried waiting for almost 5 minutes after powering off at login screen by holding the power button, after then powering the device on, but it still proceeds to boot normally. It seem like shutting down by software causes this issue to happen somehow at the next boot up.
Please write down any suggestions or possible solutions to this issue so that my device can boot Ubuntu normally.
Thank you.
Edit:
Here are the logs from the stuck boot session.
https://pastebin.com/iGQJtUW3

Solved by downgrading the nvidia proprietary driver to version 545, also works by using nouveau instead.
Edit:
Alternatively, if using 545 fails the nvidia tools, use 550 open kernel version.
